# Is it possible to detect DisclosureGroup has opened/closed or tapped?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a simple `DisclosureGroup`, can I detect if is it tapped or opened?

```
DisclosureGroup {
  Text(description)
} label: {
  Text("title")
}
```

Comment: Try the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/disclosuregroup)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is an initialiser that allows you to do exactly that:

```swift
@State private var isExpanded = false

var body: some View {
    DisclosureGroup(isExpanded: $isExpanded) {
        Text(description)
    } label: {
        Text("title")
    }
}
```